# Java -Xmx1028m not working in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, unix

I am trying to use the command "java -Xmx1028m"

It is just giving me the list of available commands after I hit enter, and it doesn't change the maximum memory size for java. Please help!

Comment: Is that the whole command line? Because you're saying "start the Java VM with a max heap size of 1028 MB", but you're not telling what to actually launch.

Answer (score 4):

It's not *meant* to change the maximum heap size for Java in general - it's meant to set it for *that invocation of the `java` command*.

So you'd typically run:

```
java -Xmx1028M com.foo.SomeApplication
```

(or an executable jar file, possibly adding extra options etc).

I don't know of any way of changing the *default* maximum heap size for Java - but doing so would assume that all applications have equal requirements anyway.

Comment: Does anyone know how to change the default maximum heap size for java on mac os x?

Answer (score 0):

-Xmx is not a 'command' per se that you can just give java and it takes effect permanently.  You need to add it to the execution of the file that you want to have a larger heap.

```
java -jar myApp.jar -Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of the java command is (always shown first if called wrong way):

```
localhost:~ arne$ java 
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
```

It does not work without a class argument not the -jar option. Try `java -Xmx1028m Test.class` and the option is accepted, but `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown.

How do you know *"it doesn't change the maximum memory size"*? I'm sure it would if you pass a correct class or jar.

Comment: You don't put `.class` when in the class name.